# trouble loading an image from a URL string inside a JSON in SwiftUI

Tags: json, swift, api, parsing, image-loading

I have this code in a SwiftUI file titled ContentView.swift:

```
struct Nasa_data: Codable {
    var copyright: String
    var date: Int
    var explanation: String
    var hdurl: String
    var media_type: String
    var service_version: String
    var title: String
    var url: String
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var nasa_datas = [Nasa_data]()
    let Nasa_image = nasa_datas.hdurl
    // this line is giving me errors ^^^^^^^^
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            AsyncImage(url: URL(string: Nasa_image))
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Nasa Data")
            .task {
                await fetchData()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func fetchData() async{
        //create the URl
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY") else {
            print ("error")
            return
    }
        // fetch the data from the url
        do {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            
            // decode the data from the url
            if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Nasa_data].self, from: data) {
 // and this line is giving me an error ^^^^^^^^
                nasa_datas = decodedResponse
            }
        } catch {
            print("data not decoded")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y-GxKhLRGyE&t=523s), to make the code. This tutorial fills out a list view with quotes from breaking bad, which I know is different. However, it is similar to what I am trying to do. I am trying to connect to an API from NASA to display an 'image of the day'. The url of the image of the day is in a JSON **array.**

​

I edited the code from this guys video a bit and am trying to use the new [Async image loader from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/asyncimage).  this line of code:

```
 let Nasa_image = nasa_datas.hdurl
```

**is giving me these errors:**

> Cannot use instance member 'nasa_datas' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

​

> Referencing subscript 'subscript(dynamicMember:)' requires wrapper 'Binding<[Nasa_data]>'

​

> Insert '$'

​

> Value of type '[Nasa_data]' has no dynamic member 'hdurl' using key path from root type '[Nasa_data]'

**and then this line**

```
if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Nasa_data].self, from: data) {
nasa_datas = decodedResponse
```

**is giving me these errors:**

> Cannot find 'nasa_datas' in scope

​

(PS I know I could do this all in MVVM with different files, but keeping it all in ContentView.swift is just easier for me due to the simplicity- let me LIIIIIVE)

​

THANK YOU SO MUCH IF SOMEONE CAN HELP!

Answer (score 0):

The first error is due to two things:, one, as the error says
you cannot use your declared `nasa_datas` to declare another
variable like you do. This is not allowed in a `View`.
Two, the array `nasa_datas` does not have `nasa_datas.hdurl`, it is
an array, not an element of it.

The second error you get is due to the miss match between the json data
you get from the server and the struct model (`[Nasa_data]`) you use to decode it into. This `[Nasa_data]` does not match the server response.

To fix your multiple errors, try this fully functional example code, using the "correct" response model `APODResponse`: (note you have to wait a few seconds to see the `Astronomy Picture of the Day`)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var apod: APODResponse?  // <-- here
 
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
          // -- here
          AsyncImage(url: URL(string: apod?.hdurl ?? "")) { phase in
            switch phase {
              case .success(let image):  image
              case .failure(let error): Text("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
              case .empty: ProgressView()
              @unknown default: fatalError()
            }
          }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Nasa Data")
        .task {
            await fetchData()
        }
    }
    
    func fetchData() async {
        //create the URl
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY") else {
            print ("error")
            return
        }
        // fetch the data from the url
        do {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            // print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)) // <-- here for future testing
            // decode the data from the url
            apod = try JSONDecoder().decode(APODResponse.self, from: data) // <-- here
        } catch {
            print("decoded error: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
}

struct APODResponse: Codable {
    let copyright, date, explanation: String
    let hdurl: String
    let mediaType, serviceVersion, title: String
    let url: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case copyright, date, explanation, hdurl
        case mediaType = "media_type"
        case serviceVersion = "service_version"
        case title, url
    }
}
```

I recommend you read the basics again at: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html
and do the tutorial at: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/
It is important to get a good grip on the basics.

Comment: If my answer has helped, could you mark it as accepted please, use the tick mark, it turns green.